# How to access the dbo.ImportError table?

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am doing an automation and one of them failed. The message is:

> Import aborted in SetBuilder. One or more errors indicating why the import was aborted may be logged to the `dbo.ImportError` table.

My question is:

**How and where can I access the `dbo.ImportError` table?**

Comment: As far as I know this is only accessible by the SFMC team. Quite annoying, but feel free to call support and they can give you a more detailed description.

Comment: any update on what's causing this error?